# Getting SVN repository rev number

Tags: svn, powershell, batch-file

Is there some `svn` or `svnadmin` command that will display the revision of a local repo?  I'd like to be able to have a Windows batch or PowerShell script that would let me zip up the repo and name it with the rev to email.

The best I can figure out is just to find the highest file in `[reporoot]\db\revs\0`, but it seems kind of clunky and I don't know if it is reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Edit) `svnversion` is not so good because it relates to the working copy, not to the repository.

`svn info` also relates to the working copy.

=> `svnlook youngest REPOS_PATH` should do it. See also [svn redbook.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svnlook.c.youngest)

Comment: svn info has a TARGET parameter.
TARGET may be either a working-copy path or a repository URL.

Answer (score 25):

```
function Get-SvnRevision($dir)
{
  ([xml](svn info $dir --xml)).info.entry.revision
}
```

[PowerShell, Subversion One Liner](http://dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2007/08/26/powershell-subversion-one-liner/)

Answer (score 4):

svnversion is the command you want. Run `svnversion --help` for an explanation of the output.

Comment: This link should help: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `svn info` which has the advantage that you don't need to run it somewhere inside the working copy (or provide a path to a working copy) -- you can pass it a URL to the repo and it displays various information about the repository including the latest revision number. `svnversion` in contrast would show the last revision number of the working copy, but this doesn't need to be identical to the revision of the repository.

Furthermore, `svn info` shows more details about the repository than `svnversion`. This might be a pro or a con, depending on your use.

Answer (score 2):

Try the VisualSVN Powershell Commands:

Get-Command -Module VisualSVN

Get-SvnRepository will give you a list of repositories and the Revision numbers. The reference is at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/

Answer (score 0):

The previous responses might not work with all versions of subversion, not sure if the older versions of subversion support xml parsed output. Can substitute "Revision" for another info property.

```
#this do an info split by new line split by : then get the second parameter where first parameter is equal to Revision
$svnRevision = (svn info "somedirectoryorurl" ) | %{$_ -split '#'} | Where-Object {($_ -split ":")[0] -eq "Revision"} | %{($_ -split ":")[1].Trim()}
```